# How to cancel delayWhen interval in order to avoid duplication of 2 parallel threads of intervals

Tags: rxjs, ngrx-effects

On my homepage when I load it I have to make 10 refreshes with 10 seconds interval. I have done it with this code:

```js
refresh$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
       ofType(HomepageActions.RefreshSuccessAction),
       delayWhen(() => interval(10000)),
       switchMap(() => {console.log(this.retriesLeft, Date().toLocaleString())
        if (!this.retriesLeft) {
          return of(HomepageActions.RefreshIsOverAction());
        }

        this.retriesLeft--;

        return this.refreshService.getFreshData().pipe(
          map((data: PagingResponse<Data>) => {
            return HomepageActions.RefreshSuccessAction({payload: data});
          }),
          catchError((error: Error) => {
            return of(new GenericErrorAction(error));
          })
        );
      })
   );
});
```

The problem I face is when the refresh is in progress and I navigate to another page and then return back. It starts doing 2x refreshes every 10 seconds. The reason is because I have navigated to another page but the delayWhen is still waiting for an interval.

When I return back to home page then the waited interval executes, but in the meanwhile I have started a new loop for refreshes. This causes two paralel loops setting intervals of 10 seconds which leads to 10 refreshes for around 50 seconds instead of 10 refreshes every 10 seconds.

Any idea how to remove all the intervals in my delayWhen on certain actions so that I avoid them being executed when I navigate back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you need to use `delayWhen()` in this scenario. You can declare an `interval(10000)` observable inside a `switchMap()`. That way, if anything emits before the `switchMap()`, it will cancel the in-progress interval and start over again.

This, combined with `takeWhile()` are what you can use to create the desired result.

```
refresh$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(HomepageActions.RefreshSuccessAction),
  switchMapTo(interval(10000).pipe(
    tap(retryCount=>console.log(9-retryCount, Date().toLocaleString())),
    takeWhile(retryCount=>retryCount<10),
    switchMap(retryCount=>
      iif(
        ()=>retryCount<10, 
        getData$,
        of(HomepageActions.RefreshIsOverAction())
    ),
  ))
))

getData$ = this.refreshService.getFreshData().pipe(
  map((data: PagingResponse<Data>) => 
    HomepageActions.RefreshSuccessAction({payload: data})
  ),
  catchError((error: Error) => 
    of(new GenericErrorAction(error))
  )
);
```

Here's the line-by-line

- Since we don't need the value from `actions$`, we use `switchMapTo()` to subscribe to the inner observable. It's the same is `switchMap(_=>interval(10000))`
- We declare an interval which will count from `0` each time it emits. This replaces the need for an external counter state, which can lead to side effect bugs.
- Use `tap()` to produce the same `console.log()` as your original example.
- `takeWhile()` will continue the observable until the inner function returns `true`. Our observable stops here until `actions$` emits a new value, restarting the entire process over again.
- Now we switchMap from our counter to an inside observable that handles the second condition.
- `iif()` is RxJS's conditional operator. It subscribe to first or second observable based on a condition function.

**Note:** I declared a new observable variable `getData$` to make the `iif()` operator a little easier to read.